# Эволюция слов (сематическая преемственность)

Tags: этимология, словообразование, значение-слов, семантика, словоизменение

Как  в лингвистике называется процесс, когда слово, используемое для обозначения того или иного явления, перестает использоваться в языке (само слово устаревает), а для обозначения того явления начинает применяться новое слово. Иными словами, на смену одному слову приходит другое.
Может это сематическая преемственность?!

Пример: 
До Революции в русском языке слово "ведомство" использовалось в двух значения: 1) ведомство - государственный орган; 2) ведомство - круг вопросов, относящихся к компетенции данного органа.

Позже для обозначения второго значения стало применяться слово "подведомственность", то есть слово "ведомство" как бы эволюционировало в "подведомственность".

Как называется вышеназванный процесс?

Answer (score 1):

Есть термин **семантическая деривация** — это изменения, возникающие в семантической структуре слова.

Процесс развития имеет конечную цель — образование нового слова, в то время как семантическая деривация как процесс изменения семантической структуры слова точной цели не имеет, она не заканчивается появлением нового слова, хотя зачастую может рассматриваться как отправная точка семантического словообразования, то есть как определённый этап развития семантической системы.

> Термин «семантическая деривация»  может быть применен как к процессу,
> так и к результату семантических переходов. Анна А. Зализняк
> утверждает, что отношения семантической производности, связывающие
> значения одного слова на уровне синхронной полисемии, и **отношения
> между значениями слова в разные моменты его истории** представляют собой
> одно и то же явление, которое и называется **семантической деривацией**
> [Зализняк 2001: 13]. Термин «семантическая деривация» используется в
> работах других лингвистов, в частности, Г.И. Кустовой, Е.В. Падучевой,
> О.Н. Трубачевым, Р.И. Розиной, М.Н. Лапшиной и др. Если рассматривать
> синхроническую и диахроническую семантическую деривацию в качестве
> одного явления, как это делает Анна А. Зализняк, то можно выделить
> следующие случаи реализации семантической деривации [Зализняк 2001:
> 18]:
>
> 1. Полисемия, т.е. наличие данного семантического соотношения между двумя значениями некоторого слова некоторого языка, например:
>    семантическая деривация «женщина» ßà «жена» во французском слове
>    femme.
> 2. Диахронический сдвиг, т.е. изменение значения, переход «а» à «в». Например, та же семантическая деривация «женщина» à «жена» в русском
>    слове «жена».
> 3. Наличие данных двух значений у одного слова (= слов, происшедших из одного слова) в двух близкородственных языках, например: франц.
>    «esperer» и исп. «esperar»: «надеяться» ßà «ждать».

https://studopedia.ru/6_5278_ponyatie-semanticheskoy-derivatsii.html

```
  на смену одному слову приходит другое
```

Архаизация слова (уход в архив), вероятно, точнее всего передаётся термином **диахронический сдвиг**, т.е. изменение значения, ну вот в вышеприведённой статье пример использования слова жена для обозначения всех женщин, а теперь только для обозначения супруги.

Answer (score 0):

Если сказать одним словом - "метаморфоз" (превращение, преобразование чего-либо). Либо - трансформация (изменение формы, преобразование).